# Recursive SQL that gets the first instance of a value up a hierarchy

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I have to do this in SQL.

I have a table called 'locations'. It contains a list of locations ranging from houses, to streets, to cities all the way up to continents.

```
 locationId      |     name         |   desiredValue
 1               |   Wimbledon      |
 2               |   Peckham        |
 3               |   London         |
 4               |   UK             |
 5               |   France         |      123
 6               |   Europe         |      456
 7               |   Australia      |
 8               |   Paris          |
```

I have a second table called 'links' which contains the link of locations, and their relation

```
 Location1      |   Location2     |    Linktype
 3              |     1           |    5
 3              |     2           |    5
 4              |     3           |    5
 6              |     4           |    5
 5              |     8           |    5
```

linktype 5 indicates that location2 is situated 'in' location1. In the example above, locationId 1 (wimbledon) is located 'in' locationId 3 (london). LocationId 3 (london) is located 'in' locationId 4 (Europe) and so on.

The linktype just describes this 'in' relationship - the link table contains other relations as well which are not pertinent to this question, I just mention it in case it needs to be in a where clause.

For a given location, I want to get the first instance in its location hierarchy that has a 'desiredValue'

For example:

1. if I was interested in Peckham, I'd like to see that Peckham has no value, that London has no value, that UK has no value but that Europe does (456).
2. If I was interested in London, I'd see that it has no value, nor does the UK, but that Europe does (456)
3. If I was interested in Europe, I'd see that it has a value (456)
4. If I was interested in Paris, I'd see that it has no value, but France does (123)

I know I should probably be using recursive CTEs for this, but I'm stumped. Any help would be greatfuly received!

Comment: Edit your question to show what you've tried so far, and what results you got, please.

Comment: A scenario that is somehow similar to yours and from which you can derive a valid query: [SQL Server recursive query](https://myadventuresincoding.wordpress.com/2014/05/02/sql-server-simple-recursive-query-example/)